# How to resize multiple image in Photoshop

Tags: image, adobe, photoshop

I have multiple images of different width and height. Now I want to make them of same Width & Height. So is there any way I can do this in photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps, this is in Photoshop as requested. There are likely easier ways to do it in Bridge or Lightroom, but this isn't too hard.

1. First, create an action in Photoshop which sets your canvas to the size you require them all to be. i.e. 1024x1024
2. Next run the Image Processor found at file > Scripts > Image
   Processor
3. Select your source and destination folders, in section 3 Resize to
   fit: the size of your canvas. i.e. W: 1024 H: 1024
4. In the "preferences" section at the bottom select Run Action and choose the action you previously created in step 1.

Outcome will be an images that are the same height or width, but with borders to make up the space that didn't fit in the desired size. i.e. a portrait image will have bands down the left and right side. A landscape image will have bands at the top and bottom. The colour of these bands is determined when you created your action in step 1.

Comment: As I am new to this technology so can you tell me how to run the scripts?

Comment: Image Processor is already a script with a GUI applied, you need not make your own. Following the steps above should result in getting you the images you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer helps you. For uploading multiple images.

- Create a folder -> Add all images in that folder -> Open a photo in Photoshop
- Go to Image -> Image Size(Ctrl + Alt + I) and set the image size you want to give.

[image: Image Sizing]

- Go to Window Menu -> Actions (Alt+F9)

[image: Actions Menu]

- Create New Action & when it is created then it will automatically start recording all the steps.

[image: Recording Action]

- Now your first image sizing is done. Now Go to File -> Automate -> Batch.

[image: Automated Menu]

- Now choose the folder of multiple images and press OK.

[image: Change Multiple Images]

**All the images are converted to given width and height.**